# Editor Image by TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I would like to use typescript to edit image(upload, zoom, rolate), i have searched to many website but have not any sample like that.Anyone help me to give tutorial or code sample link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to use typescript to edit image(upload, zoom, rolate), i have searched to many website but have not any sample like that.Anyone help me to give tutorial or code sample link.

You can do this by

1.) Upload : loading the image in a canvas

2.) Manipulating the canvas pixels

3.) Write out the canvas data using an image

> I am trying to rewrite code from javescript to typescript so i would like to have code sample use typescript systax to references.

It is a non trivial amount of effort. There is a library that does all this : http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/

You can use it as is from TypeScript by just creating a file `darkroom.d.ts` with the following contents:

```
declare var DarkRoom:any;
```

More on migration : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: Thanks. but i am trying to rewrite code from javescript to typescript so i would like to have  code sample use typescript systax to references.

Comment: @Dungnpd its a non trivial amount of effort to write this code. You should leverage the OSS already out there